# Perimeter of an isosceles trapezoid in function of b

Tags: geometry

"In the isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ with bases $AD$ and $BC$ (being $AD$ the larger base), $\angle$ABC = $2$$\angle$CDA. If $AB$ = $BC$ = $b$, the perimeter of the trapezoid is?"

I thought that this problem was very easy, but i can't figure it out. The main problem is the length of the base $AD$.

I tried with similarity of some triangles that are formed with the heights and the diagonals of the trapezoid, but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perimeter is $5b$.

Note:
$$mABC+mDAB=180 \Rightarrow mDAB=60.$$
Drop heights $BE$ and $CF$, then:
$$\cos{(mBAE)}=\frac{AE}{AB} \Rightarrow AE=b\cos{60}=\frac{b}{2}.$$
Hence:
$$P=AB+BC+CD+(AE+DF)+EF=5b.$$